# MySQL query hanging on copying to tmp table

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables

I'm stuck with a query hanging on 'copying to tmp table' for about 25 seconds according to the profiling.

The query is used for forecasting the number of results after filtering by job_type / job_category. So what I want is a list containing all job_types with the number of profiles matching this category.

Some explaination of the used tables:

```
jb_select_boxes    | containing 191 rows, of which 40 job_types are used
jb_users           | containing around 175k rows
jb_seeker_profiles | containing a row for every user, so also about 175k
```

The query being used to acchieve this (Works, but takes about 25 seconds)

```
SELECT
    sb.name_nl, sb.name, count(*) as nr
FROM
    jb_select_boxes as sb 
LEFT JOIN
    jb_seeker_profiles as sp ON job_category1 = sb.name OR job_category2 = sb.name 
JOIN
    jb_users as u ON u.id = sp.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    jb_seeker_profiles_edu as spe ON u.id = spe.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    jb_addresses as a ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    jb_seeker_profiles_exp AS exp ON u.id = exp.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    jb_resumes AS jbr ON u.id = jbr.user_id AND jbr.type='html2pdf' AND jbr.resume_privacy='378'
WHERE
    sb.group_name = 'job_types' AND u.status = 'seeker' AND u.completed = 1
GROUP BY
    sb.name_nl
ORDER BY
    nr DESC
```

Explain result of the query:
[image: Explain result of the query:]

I already tried to play with the max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size variables but without positive effects. Values are now at 256M.

Comment: if you want positive effects rewrite the query so it doesn't create a tmp table.
if you can't - make sure it doesn't read 175524 rows from u.
If you can't - create a tmpdir on a RAM disk

Comment: @akuzminsky Yeah if i just knew how to prevent the creation of the tmp table... :) I think it will need to read all the users, since they need to be counted to show the numbers of users in each category. Will check about the tmpdir on RAM disk suggestion. However I hope there is a solution rewriting the query...